# Redirecting INTO a Java program?

Tags: java, apache-karaf

In a project, I'm trying to set up an automated build system for Apache Karaf (there are several commands I need to run in Karaf to set up a working environment on a fresh install). Karaf contains a batch/script file that sets several parameters, and then calls the actual Java program. Essentially, I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
java MyProgramClass.class < commandTextFile.txt
```

But when I try this it doesn't do anything. My goal is to simply copy the karaf.bat file, modify it slightly (as below) to make a "karaf-install.bat" that I can just run. The part I've modified of karaf.bat is below, and all I've done is add `< "C:\commandFile.txt` at the end (the following is all on one line, broken for readability):

```
"%JAVA%" %JAVA_OPTS% %OPTS% -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" 
  -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\endorsed;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\endorsed;%KARAF_HOME%\lib\endorsed" 
  -Djava.ext.dirs="%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\ext;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\ext;%KARAF_HOME%\lib\ext"
  -Dkaraf.instances="%KARAF_HOME%\instances" -Dkaraf.home="%KARAF_HOME%" 
  -Dkaraf.base="%KARAF_BASE%" -Dkaraf.data="%KARAF_DATA%" 
  -Djava.util.logging.config.file="%KARAF_BASE%\etc\java.util.logging.properties" 
  %KARAF_OPTS% %MAIN% %ARGS% < "C:\commandFile.txt"
```

However, Karaf shows nothing. It just runs as if I executed it as normal; my commands are not executed. Is there a way to redirect INTO a java program from the console? Am I doing it way wrong?

For what it's worth, this will eventually be done on both Windows and OS X, but I'm focusing on Windows at the moment.

**Update:** turns out that this seems to work for me on OS X (Karaf struggles (by saying "Command not found: "), but I think it's because it's getting the commands before it's initialized everything), but Windows is still doesn't even get the commands. I'll poke around more.

Comment: Why needing to mess with endorsed directories?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: Ext.dir and endorsed.dir.  This is usually not necessary

Comment: How long is the command line?  Windows has a fairly short command line limit.  It's possible your addition is being clipped.

Comment: It's exactly as above (the big long one). I'll look into it clipping my command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just going to write this issue off as Karaf weirdness, seeing as it works on OS X. I was able to work around it by using the `client` program that comes with Karaf by doing (on OS X in a .sh file):

```
"$KARAF/bin/client" "karaf_command_here"
```

or (on Windows in a .bat file)

```
call "%KARAF%\bin\client.bat" "karaf_command_here"
```

And instead of having a list of commands to pipe into Karaf, I just made the list of commands a shell/batch script file that would call Karaf's `client` for each command. Not as pretty as I'd have liked it, but it got the job done.

(Note you need to start Karaf before using the `client` with `start` (and close it with `stop`)).

Answer (score 1):

When piping INTO, you can read it from `System.in`.

Consider it a Reader, not an InputStream.

Comment: I'm not modifying the Java program. Instead, it's an already existing Java program that's interactive and gets input from the user via the command line, and what I'm trying to do is automatically feed it commands.

Comment: Unless it reads user input from the CMD.EXE window, you cannot make this work.  Look in the manual if the program supports a flag to read a command file at startup

Comment: It does read input from the command prompt. "it's an already existing Java program that's interactive and gets input from the user via the command line."

Comment: Then it should work.  If not, have a look at the source code to see what happens